# Which storage configuration files do you change to update a Content Service endpoint?

Tags: dxa, content-delivery, sites-9.5, discovery-service, content-service

I'm updating a Tridion Sites 9.5 (training) environment and can see the DXA application has the wrong Content Service endpoint.

The DXA site log shows:

> Sdl.Tridion.Api.GraphQL.Client.Exceptions.GraphQLClientException:
> Unable to connect to the remote server  ---> System.Net.WebException:
> Unable to connect to the remote server --->
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
> because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
> time, or established connection failed because connected host has
> failed to respond 10.x.x.x:8081 at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
> SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
> System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
> Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
> ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
> exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The service instead should be at localhost:8081 instead. Visiting http://localhost:8081/content.svc/health shows:

`{"status":"UP","details":{"application":{"status":"UP"},"diskSpace":{"status":"UP","details":{"total":85896196096,"free":74334662656,"threshold":10485760}}}}`

And `http://localhost:8081/content.svc` returns an expected `{"error":"invalid_grant"}` (I haven't modified anything for authorization).

Questions:

**Where do we set the URL for the Content Service? I think it goes in `cd_storage_conf` but is that *just* in the Content Service config folder?**

Checking \content\config\cd_storage_conf.xml, I can see:

`<Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="http://10.x.x.x:8081/content.svc"/>`

I think this should be instead:

`<Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="http://localhost:8081/content.svc"/>`

But I'm confused because I've seen examples that also shows the Content Service URL/URI in the Discovery Service's cd_storage_conf.

**After making changes, do we run `java -jar discovery-registration.jar update` command in the Discovery Config folder as well?**

Running discovery-registration reports the following.

```
Created or Updated Capabilities:
{
  "id" : "DefaultTokenService",
  "lastUpdateTime" : 1659478275651,
  "uri" : "http://dxd.tridiondemo.com:8082/token.svc"
}
{
  "id" : "DefaultWeb",
  "lastUpdateTime" : 1659478275764
}
{
  "id" : "DefaultContentService",
  "lastUpdateTime" : 1659478275815,
  "uri" : "http://localhost:8081/content.svc"
}
```

So I think I updated the service endpoint, but after the changes, the registration command, and restarting both the Discovery and Content Service doesn't seem to change the DXA error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this particular error may have been related to something else, either authentication or not restarting the services.

In short, to update the URL/URI for the Content Service (when running as Windows Service in a test or training environment):

1. Update `cd_storage_conf.xml` in the Content Service configuration folder.
2. [(Re)install the Content Service](https://docs.rws.com/816112/329088/sdl-tridion-sites-9-5-main-documentation/installing-the-session-enabled-content-service-as-a-microservice), using the auto-register switch to register the Content Service microservice as a Capability.

`ConfigRepository` will have:

```
<Roles>
    <Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="http://localhost:8081/content.svc"/>
</Roles>
```

Per the [documentation](https://docs.rws.com/986894/300452/tridion-sites-9-6-main-documentation/registering-the-content-service-microservice-as-a-capability), you only need to add the Content Service URI in the Discovery Service cd_storage_conf.xml if you did *not* set auto-register and you want to manually configure the Content Service.

Otherwise, leave out the Content Service in the Discovery Service, skip the `java -jar discovery-registration.jar` command, and auto register the Content Service instead.